# How to include keys and values from a dictionary in a regex expresion in python 3?

Tags: python, regex, ruby, dictionary

I need to create and modify regexes that need to match for any key or value inside a dictionary.

Doing this in Ruby is relatively easy, for example, like this:

```
names = {"John White"=>"一","George Black"=>"二","Mary Jane Fields"=>"三"}
string = "This involves John White (from now on: 'JW'), George Black (from now on: 'GB') and Mary Jane Fields (from now on: 'MJF'). JW wanted GB to tell MJF that he (GB) was with JW when MJF called JW."
names.each do |k,v|
    string.gsub! k,v
end
names.each_value do |v| 
    short_name = /(#{v}) \(from now on: '(.{2,4})'\)/.match(string).to_a
    string.gsub! short_name[2].to_s, short_name[1].to_s
end
puts string
```

This gives the following result:

```
This involves 一 (from now on: '一'), 二 (from now on: '二') and 三 (from now on: '三'). 一 wanted 二 to tell 三 that he (二) was with 一 when 三 called 一.
```

where all names (the real one and the adhoc name given after "from now on:") were replaced with the value in the hash.

When trying to update a similar program from Ruby into Python, though, I am having trouble inserting key/values in the regex in a re.sub command or similar.
The beginning of the code works fine if done as follows:

```
import re 
names = {"John White":"一","George Black":"二","Mary Jane Fields":"三"}
string = "This involves John White (from now on: JW), George Black (from now on: GB) and Mary Jane Fields (from now on: MJF). JW wanted GB to tell MJF that he (GB) was with JW when MJF called JW."
for key,value in names.items():
    string = re.sub(str(key),str(value),string)
print(string)
```

But the second transformation is tricky since I cannot enter the value into the regex expression. All of the following give different errors or just do not match. For Example, the following creates match objects but does not capture nor modifies the string:

```
for value in names.values():    
    pattern = re.search(str(value)+' \(from now on: (.{2,4})\)',string)
    string = re.sub(str(pattern),str(value),string)
```

Many other things do not work either. Any way to include calls into dictionary values inside regex expressions? Specifically, in a re.sub command?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that this way of replacing can be problematic if some of the replacements contain patterns. For example, `{"foo": "bar", "bar": "foo"}` requires a different approach.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context for this? There may be a better approach. Why the strings like `'三'`, for example?

Answer (score 0):

You should be searching for `key` when you are trying to set `pattern`, not `value`. Also, you need to extract the contents of group 1, which you can do with `.group(1)`. You can then do both substitutions at once by making an alternation regex pattern out of the `key` and its abbreviation:

```
import re 
names = {"John White":"一","George Black":"二","Mary Jane Fields":"三"}
string = "This involves John White (from now on: JW), George Black (from now on: GB) and Mary Jane Fields (from now on: MJF). JW wanted GB to tell MJF that he (GB) was with JW when MJF called JW."
for key,value in names.items():
    abbrev = re.search(key + r' \(from now on: (.{2,4})\)',string).group(1)
    string = re.sub(r'\b' + key + '|' + abbrev + r'\b', value, string)
print(string)
```

Output:

```
This involves 一 (from now on: 一), 二 (from now on: 二) and 三 (from now on: 三). 一 wanted 二 to tell 三 that he (二) was with 一 when 三 called 一.
```

Answer (score 0):

Casting the `pattern` object to a string will result in something like

`"<re.Match object; span=(14, 33), match='一 (from now on: JW)'>"`

which is obviously not what you are looking for. You should use the match group at index 1:

```
string = re.sub(pattern[1], str(value), string)
```

As a side note, avoid using names from the Python standard library (such as `string`) as variable names.